# I have download the android studio 2.2.2,use the gradle 2.14.1 gradle command to compile the project,but failed?

Tags: android

i have download the android studio 2.2.2,use the gradle 2.14.1 gradle command to compile the project,but failed?

I input gradlew build but failed

the erro log is following

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
  >    Required by:
  >        :MyApplication:unspecified
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.2/gradle-2.2.2.pom'.
  >   Server sent an unsupported extension: type_35
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 5):

in *build.gradle* change this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }
```

to this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
 }
```